# change Message UIAlertController swift

Tags: swift

i do a counter app and in I have many messages error for different case.
And I would like to know if is possible to change only the message of the alert for have only one alert.

'''

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateText), name: Notification.Name("updateCalcul"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(displayError), name: Notification.Name("error"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(displayError2), name: Notification.Name("error2"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(displayError3), name: Notification.Name("error3"), object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@objc func updateText() {
    textView.text = calcul.calculString
}

@objc func displayError(){

    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Zéro!", message: "Un operateur est déja mis !", preferredStyle: .alert)
              alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
              self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func displayError2(){
      let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Zéro!", message: "Entrez une expression correcte !", preferredStyle: .alert)
                 alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                 return self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
@objc func displayError3(){
       let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Zéro!", message: "Démarrez un nouveau calcul !", preferredStyle: .alert)
       alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
       return self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

}

'''

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**

Make an extension of UIAlertController like this:

```
import UIKit

extension UIAlertController {
    class func showAlertWithOK(viewController: UIViewController, alertTitle: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel))
        viewController.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
UIAlertController.showAlertWithOK(viewController: self, alertTitle: "Your title", message: "your message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a lazy variable similar to this

```
lazy var alertViewController: UIAlertController = {
    let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertViewController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    return alertViewController
}()
```

then inside your method, change alert's `title` and `message` properties before presenting.

```
@objc func displayError(){
    alertViewController.title = "Your title here"
    alertViewController.message = "Your message here"
    self.present(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For more generic cases you can have same handy extensions

```
extension UIViewController {
    func alert(title: String, message: String? = nil, action: (() -> ())? = nil) {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        action?()
       }
       alertController.addAction(action)
       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```